# tikz: label offset insied axis environment

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have trouble with label offset insied axis environment. This is [my minimal example](http://paste.arn-fai.net/?2874724): I used no paste service to avoid flood text. In particular, the problem lies in line 258:

```
\node[left=1pt of {(axis cs:586, 19.28)}, outer sep=1pt,fill=white] {node};
```

It seems to not be able to read axis cartesian system.

Can you help me?

Comment: Use `\node[scale = 1.75, fill=yellow, draw=black, circle, minimum width=3pt, inner
  sep=0pt, label={[fill=white,outer sep=1pt]left:node}]  at (axis cs:586, 19.28) {} ;` and remove `set layers` or add at least a comma after that key.

Comment: The missing comma after `set layers` is my typo. BTW, thank you!